# Getting junk data when trying to retrieve elements from a PROGMEM array on Arduino

Tags: arduino

My code looks something like this:

```
#define SIZE_OF_ARRAY 1000
const long myArray[SIZE_OF_ARRAY] PROGMEM = {
  1610514120L,
  1613070480L,
  1615630980L,
  1618194720L,
  1620759660L,
  1623322440L,
  1625879820L,
  1628430600L,
  1630975920L,
  1633518300L,
  1636060500L,
  1638603840L,
  1641148500L,
  1643694540L,
  ... // All the way to 1000 elements  
}
  
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  for( int i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_ARRAY; i++){
    long currentNumber = myArray[i];
    // These also do not work:
    //long currentNumber = pgm_read_word_near(myArray + i);
    //long currentNumber = pgm_read_dword_near(myArray + i);
    Serial.println(currentNumber);
  }
}
```

But when I run this code, I get completely random junk data:

```
0
65536
0
-1195853640
8843185
-566231498
-310626819
-854754529
263210495
-325068311
-159567983
-1770239
-29784074
1054840810
-293611553
-436273185
-566231498
-310626819
-854754529
263210495
... all the way up to 1000
```

How can I access that array to get the data I put in it? I am not very familiar with C and the difference between variables and pointers, but it works without the PROGMEM flag so I assumed it would work with it as well.

Comment: The progmem is on different bus and you are using it as it's simple address to RAM. There is whole section on this topic on arduino.cc. Btw this applies only for the old AVR devices, for example Atmega4809 (used in arduino nano every or uno wifi rev.2) has flat memory emulation, so you can use one pointer for all (you don't need PROGMEM and functions to load data from progmem space)

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/utilities/progmem/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP simply did not bother to read how to use PROGMEM and decided that it is much easier to use us for that task.

Comment: I did read that documentation, and tried using `pgm_read_byte_near`, `pgm_read_word_near`, and also `pgm_read_dword_near`. none of which worked. I couldn't understand the documentation well enough so I asked here in the simplest way I could to get an answer. The documentation does not reference `long` data types at all, so I am at a loss

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the answer was to use:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  for( int i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_ARRAY; i++){
    unsigned long currentNumber = pgm_read_dword_near(myArray + i);
    Serial.println(currentNumber);
  }
}
```

And to redefine the `long` array as:

```
const unsigned long myArray[SIZE_OF_ARRAY] PROGMEM = {
  1610514120UL,
  1613070480UL,
  1615630980UL,
  1618194720UL,
  1620759660UL,
  ...
}
```

Because I was also running into `long` overflow errors